# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate with same keystore

Tags: android, flutter

im using flutter, after i formatted my pc when i want to build and upload apk file to the play store show me bellow, error by the way i have project with same keystore

[image]

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1:   ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1:   ]

Comment: is your package name the same?

Comment: can you show what error are you facing?

Comment: lasagnakid77 yes i have same project i just changed some bugs as i said after formatting o faced this error

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading this software (GUI) https://keystore-explorer.org/ . I saw with this tool that my Keystore had diferent certificates and aliases. So I could compare which one Google Play was asking for. Then I could sign with the correct alias and upload an update of my app.

Comment: Thank you, this was a life saver for me! I thought I was using the correct keystore until I used the keystore explorer tool and found out it was the wrong one, and the correct one was found only on my backup computer!

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like you are trying to upload an update of your app or trying to sign apk with different security certificate than the previous version.

For more details check [Android Developers Guide for signing APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: Then your keystore file must be tempered. Try to sign APK with new certificate and publish a new copy of App

Comment: i have source in the bitbucket when i clone and build its same error

Answer (score 0):

When you have formatted, have you kept a copy of the keystore (*.jks or *.keystore file)? You should sign your APK (or App Bundle) using the same one you used to upload the first versions of your app to Google Play Console.

If you have lost that keystore file, since it looks like you are enrolled in Google Play Signing, you can request your upload key to be reset by contacting the Developer Support directly: see "Create a new upload key" at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423"